# PHP MySQL inserting multiple values from drop box selections

Tags: php, mysql, join, insert

I have a table populated by a MySQL table, and I am trying to insert the selected rows from the table into another table.

**The table look like below:**
[image].

There are first three fields in the table are coming from two other tables depending on the Field values.

And the drop down selections are provided by user using:

```
$sql = "SELECT project_proposals.id, project_proposals.title, project_proposals.description, project_proposals.academicname, flux_student_records.studentname, flux_student_records.id, flux_student_records.programme, flux_student_records.academicdiscipline FROM project_proposals JOIN flux_student_records ON project_proposals.academicdiscipline = flux_student_records.academicdiscipline 
WHERE project_proposals.academicdiscipline = '$academicdiscipline' AND flux_student_records.studentname = '$studentname'";

$retval = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

What will be the best way to insert these multiple selected rows into another table please? Thanks.

Comment: I always looped trough all filled in fields and inserting them one by one...

Comment: you can use a insert into select ex: 
    INSERT INTO a (a1, a2, a3) SELECT b1, b2, b3 FROM b limit 100; 
no need for PHP

Comment: use while loop to fetch all rows and insert to another table up to loop ends.

Comment: I tried that @Claudio Pinto. The problem with that is linking inserts with selected dropdown. It inserts the Limit X values, and only the last value of the dop box for all inserts.

Comment: @SkyRamon and Kuttyraj - any examples?

Comment: @NoooSmyth, are you trying to insert in one table from a posted form? If so, looping throw the POST array and inserting one by one should solve your problem. don't forget to sanitise your queries though

Comment: @ClaudioPinto yes. But the posted form is partly populated from another table (first three columns in the image above). I want to insert ONLY selected rows using the drop down values into the new table. Thanks re: sanitising queries. Will do once I figure out how to insert

Comment: The source of the data to build the table and form is not relevant, just place-hold all the information you need in hidden fields. After that you handle the $_POST array as you would normally do. By submitting all the data you want to store you eliminate the need to retrieve data from the database again, therefore not having the problem of different source tables

Comment: @ClaudioPinto thank you. This worked perfectly for me. Now I have a new problem - one of the columns is not imploding the array :-( - but I'll post that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

"select into" is the way to go.

```
    SELECT into YourNewTable select project_proposals.id, project_proposals.title, project_proposals.description, project_proposals.academicname, flux_student_records.studentname, flux_student_records.id, flux_student_records.programme, flux_student_records.academicdiscipline FROM project_proposals JOIN flux_student_records ON project_proposals.academicdiscipline = flux_student_records.academicdiscipline 
WHERE project_proposals.academicdiscipline = '$academicdiscipline' AND flux_student_records.studentname = '$studentname'";
```

Hope you find this usefull.

Comment: Interesting to know. Does it also insert rows that are already in the database or Table?

Comment: "select into " creates a new table from a select statement. So you can narrow your result using the "where" condition . It creates a table, field names and data types automatically .

Comment: @leo thank you - this is good to know. It didn't really work for me in this case - but I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trough an post and then do some thing with that information.
So for example:

```
    <?php

function readDataForwards($dbh) {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM yourdb';
  try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
      $data = $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
      print $data;
      #insert the data into another database
      #you can also filter some duplicated items that you already 
      #have in the database
    }
    $stmt = null;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
}

    ?>
```

this would output: the rows in the database
but it could also insert the rows into your database.

Comment: Thanks @SkyRamon. Will give this a go.

Comment: @NoooSmyth let me know how it turned out :)